# what will be the declaration of follow (in C)?

Tags: c

How can we declare the variable which contains constraints? I'm new to C so sorry for rookie questions. What is the procedure for these types of declarations? And also if I create an array what maximum size could it have? For example, P[3] is of 4.

```
      Constraint 
      1. 300<n<1000
```

Comment: We impose constraints by writing code that complains at run-time if the constraint is violated. And why do you wish to create an array of a maximum size? Sounds like you have a problem, but you ask about what you perceive to be to solution instead.

Comment: C imposes few constraints other than that the value fit in the space reserved for the variable. An array of size N can only be indexed from 0 to N-1.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we declare <strike>the</strike> a variable which contains constraints?

A variable that "contains" constraints means a variable that is inherently limited or protected by constraints declared in its definition.

In C, that is not really possible because the code neccessary to guard for the constraints cannot be declared with the variable. In C++ you could write a class.

You could write a module in C , e.g. `myvar.c` that creates, manages and destroys a "thing" that is your "variable with constraints" but I don't think that will be what you want as it will not be elegant.

So, in summary, you cannot declare a variable with constraints in C, but you can have checks in your code to make sure the variable does not violate your constraints. Those checks must be everywhere in the code where you modify your variable.